# Spring websocket stomp client how to capture the connection is lost？

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket

I use [spring websocket](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) stomp client. Below is a code fragment：

```
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<Transport>(2);
transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
transports.add(new RestTemplateXhrTransport());

WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
headers.add("Cookie", client.getCookieString());

SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);

WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
ListenableFuture<StompSession> future = 
   stompClient.connect(configuration.getApp().getWebsocketServerBase() + "/websocket/sa", headers, new MyWebSocketHandler());

future.addCallback(new SuccessCallback<StompSession>() {
    public void onSuccess(StompSession stompSession) {
        System.out.println("on Success!");
    }
}, new FailureCallback() {
    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println("on Failure!");
    }
});
```

It works, but when websocket server is closed, the client doesn't receive the message.

How to listener server close event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution.

MyWebSocketHandler implements StompSessionHandler like this:

```
private class MyWebSocketHandler implements StompSessionHandler {
    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession stompSession, StompHeaders stompHeaders) {

    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession stompSession, StompCommand stompCommand, StompHeaders stompHeaders, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(StompSession stompSession, Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instanceof ConnectionLostException) {
            // if connection lost, call this
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders stompHeaders, Object o) {
    }
}
```

You can see method handleTransportError. Thank you.

Reference [Spring WebSocket Document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) 25.4.13 STOMP Client.

Comment: ConnectionLostException:   Raised when the connection for a STOMP session is lost rather than closed.

I use it.

Reference:
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.3.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/stomp/package-summary.html

Comment: By chance, do you remember how you recovered from this exception?

Comment: @Jeff https://github.com/hookszhang/fort-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/boyuanitsm/fort/sdk/ResourceSyncService.java line:140, when i receive connection lost exception, connect and repeat

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also catch [SessionDisconnectEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-appplication-context-events):

> `SessionDisconnectEvent` — published when a STOMP session ends. The DISCONNECT may have been sent from the client, or it may also be automatically generated when the WebSocket session is closed. In some cases this event may be published more than once per session. Components should be idempotent with regard to multiple disconnect events.